# React Navigation presentation modal - disable parent screen from scaling down (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a bottom modal that slides up from bottom, has a transparent background, and can be swiped down (exact same as Instagram's various bottom modals). I can almost achieve this with:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="testModal"
  component={ChatAttachments}
  options={{
    headerShown: false,
    headerTransparent: true,
    presentation: "modal",
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    gestureDirection: "vertical",
    gestureResponseDistance: 500,
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      opacity: 1,
    },
  }}
/>
```

But is there a way to disable the parent screen from scaling down?

Another option could be using `presentation: "transparentModal"` but that doesn't give me the swipe down ability.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gestureEnabled: true,` in your options; also, for swiping effects, you need to manually add an animated style, like this one:

```
cardStyleInterpolator: ({current: {progress}}) => {
   const opacity = progress.interpolate({
     inputRange: [0, 1],
     outputRange: [0, 1],
     extrapolate: 'clamp',
   });
   return {cardStyle: {opacity}};
},
```